# Relation between Torque, Speed and Voltage

Tags: voltage, motor, dc, dc-motor, torque

In my application, I require a DC motor that can operate a fixed load at different speeds. Is this possible? I know for sure that torque varies with current and speed varies with the voltage. Does this mean that voltage has no effect on torque and that the dc motor will generate the same torque even at lower voltage?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I am sorry, the link still doesn't answer my question. It may be due to a gap in my understanding of the relation between torque speed and voltage.

Comment: you are correct about the gap, read again V controls DCR current which causes torque until BEMF reduces internal voltage and current .  V controls speed RPM/V with no load, I controls torque